# What's the best way to use shortcuts and autocomplete to create a new object in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: object, autocomplete, intellij-idea, new-operator, shortcut

`Object` + `shortcut` ➜ `Object object = new Object();`

Whether there is such shortcut?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`new Obj`, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete to `new Object()`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (`Refactor` | **Introduce Variable**):

```
Object o = new Object();
```

Change name if needed and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.

For the more convenient solution utilizing the live templates feature please [check the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834284/104891) from [@MarcG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3411681/marcg).

Comment: With all due respect to your generally good and thoughtful answers, this is probably just as bad as simply typing everything by hand.

Answer (score 21):

As of **2017**, improving on @aleksander's answer, I believe the best way to create a new object as efficiently as possible in Intellij IDEA, is this (click to enlarge):

[image]

1. Go to `Settings > Live Template`.
2. Then click the `+` to the right of the window, to add a new Live Template.
3. Choose the abbreviation you want (Like `n` or `newo`). Description could be `new Object` .
4. Add the template text: `$Clazz$ $obj$ = new $Clazz$($END$);`
5. Click que `Edit Variables` button, and the fill in the `Clazz` and `obj` **Expression** and **Default Value** as shown in the picture above.
6. Don't forget to click `Define` next to `No applicable contexts`, to define `Java > Statement` as the context.

Now test it: Go to the editor, type `n` and then the `TAB` key.

Comment: Great!, a popular daily developer need which I think should be added by default inside IntelliJ Idea

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own Live Template. Press Crtl+Alt+Shift+S (go to Settings), then go to tab Live Templates and write down something similar to below and you will have new shortcut (newo+tab).

[image]