# How to make appcode automatically assign my expression to a variable?

Tags: autocomplete, appcode

I can't figure out the shortcut combination to use in this scenario.  I am using AppCode with IdeaVim plugin.

How do I make appcode automatically assign my expression to a variable? For example, I have written:

```
[self getString]
```

which returns an NSString *.

Is there a hotkey I can press which will make this statement be assigned to the right kind of variable? So, something like:

```
NSString * newVariable = [self getString];
```

I think this is possible in Eclipse+java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Refactor` | `Extract` | **Variable**.  See also the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11892034/104891). Keyboard shortcut for this refactoring can be changed in `Preferences` | `Keymap`. Default shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: CrazyCoder, I don't see "Introduce Variable" option either in Refactor menu or after selecting Refactor after mouse right click. I am using AppCode with IdeaVim plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using IdeaVim plugin in AppCode. I had to Press ^T to get the "Refactor This" popup menu and press 1 for Variable. So, the answer to my question is:

press ^T then 1.

The more I use AppCode+IdeaVim, the more I love it. Thanks CrazyCoder to point me in the right direction.