# Intellij Type autocompletion when initializing an object

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to set up Intellij to auto complete a type when you new up an object. for example i type

`String name = new`

If i hit CTRL + SHIFT + Space it adds the type like

`String name = new String();`

I'd like it to do this automatically when i hit space after the new keyword

Comment: I'd be uncomfortable with doing something like this; suppose you were declaring an interface instead - i.e. `Map<String, Object> theMap` - what would go after `new`?

Comment: maybe its a language difference thing. i'm a c# developer and based on that i would expect new Map. but i guess that because you declare an interface like 'IMap<String, Object> theMap = new Map()'

Comment: The thing is that you can't instantiate an interface, so expecting a new Map is kind of like expecting a new Object - you've got to be explicit.  There are also objects which are implicitly instantiated, such as `String s = "";`.  It probably does boil down to a language difference; I don't see much use in this feature.  IntelliJ *will*, however, offer suggestions after typing part of the object's name.

Comment: cool, looks like i need to learn the differences with interfaces in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using **Introduce Variable** refactoring instead as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11892034/104891).

Comment: Can you comment on why? I'm a C# dev and still new to Java

Comment: See comments from @Makoto, this way you can complete the implementation after `new` and then introduce a variable of the interface type with a hotkey (interface will be suggested automatically), saves a lot of typing.