# What is the fastest/most effective way to create a "new ArrayList" in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, arraylist

My goal is to type the following statement as fast/effective as possible using IntelliJ IDEA:

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

This is what I tried:

- use code completion `List<String> list = new |`, but too much to type
- use post fix code completion `new ArrayList<>().var|`, but still too much to type

Note `|` means Code complete here

In NetBeans there is a simple template like "al", which creates the statement above. 
I did not found such a live template in IDEA for that. Did I miss an important usage pattern in IDEA?

EDIT: That is not a dumb noobie question. I recently switched to IDEA and haven't grasp all things to be productive. Yes, I could define my own live template and then persist it in a configuration file to share it with my working computer or create a plugin, which provides my template.  But that is not the question. **Is there a fast standard/built-in way to do it?**

Comment: My solution (that's widely applicable to all sorts of snippets and IDEs but might not be for everyone) was to learn to touch-type.

Comment: Can't you create code templates there too? A quick google search yields many results. I'm no expert at IntelliJ thus comment only.

Comment: A fun way to learn touch typing is found [here](http://store.steampowered.com/app/246580/The_Typing_of_The_Dead_Overkill/).

Comment: You can type `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`, copy it to your clipboard, and paste it at any time :)

Comment: Or use any hotkey-program that automatically enters this text after hitting a specific hotkey.

Comment: Live Templates. But I usually write "new AL", ctrl+shit+Space to autocomplete, then intruduce variable.

Comment: @Ben your question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834284/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Yes, that matches my question! Thank you. But gives no answer, if there is a fast default way.

Comment: @Ben there is nothing default. you will need to add a template.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own templates if you feel you need more to what IntelliJ provides

Read [this link on IntellJ on code completion](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/custom_language_support/code_completion.html)

Comment: Can you include the essential parts of that link here, or just quote them? It's better if questions and answers at SO are self-contained. Also the link could become invalid in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I know, but is there anything default in IDEA for that? I do not like to configure my IDE for that.

Comment: I did not knew that