# Quick object instantiation with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Sometimes I need to instantiate new object with the following pattern

```
 ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName();
```

Does IntelliJ IDEA have any shortcut, live template or any other way quickly accomplish such statements based on `ObjectName`?

Comment: Is that really a hard job especially with intellisense?

Comment: This may help...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891641/whats-the-best-way-to-use-shortcuts-and-autocomplete-to-create-a-new-object-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can type:

`new ObjectName().var` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

to have IntelliJ expand it to:

```
ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName();
```

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I need

Comment: I suggest you post this same handy Answer on the linked Question of which this Question is a duplicate.